# Specifying Grunt output to a dynamic parallel folder

Tags: gruntjs

**The Context**

I'm new to Grunt and am trying to learn a bit by modifying the [meanjs](http://meanjs.org) boilerplate to support [stylus](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/), I would like to keep my precompiled css assets organized in modular buckets, as recommended by the current meanjs defaults.

**The Question**

I have the following file structure:

```
- app
- config
- public
 - modules
  - foo
   - assets
    - stylesheets
    ...
   - css
   ...
...
```

How can I use Grunt to take Stylus .styl files in the `public/modules/*/assets/stylesheets` directory, and have them compile to the `public/modules/*/css` directory?

**Naive Attempt:**

Below is an example attempt, which didn't get very far.

```
stylus: {
  compile: {
    files: [{
      dest: '../../css',
      src: 'public/modules/*/assets/stylesheets/*.styl',
      ext: '.css',
      expand: true
    }]
  }
}
```

This results in: `File ../../css/public/modules/foo/assets/stylesheets/baz.css created.`

If I leave "dest" empty, it does properly compile but the output is in the assets/stylesheets folder (as expected).  I'm sure there is a clean way to do this, but I don't know yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the src, dest, cwd, as well as using the hidden rename options of grunt should get stylus files in your desired format.

example:

```
stylus: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      compress: true
    },
    files: [{
      cwd: 'public/modules',
      dest: 'public/modules',
      src: ['*/assets/stylesheets/*.styl'],
      expand: true,
      rename: function(dest, src) {
        var path = require('path');
        var module = src.split(path.sep).slice(0,1)[0];
        return path.join(dest, module + '/css/' + module + '.css');
      }
    }]
  }
},
```

[grunt tricks - customize file output rename](http://dontkry.com/posts/code/grunt-tricks.html#customize-file-output-rename)